# BeautifulSoup scraping - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am practicing scraping with BeautifulSoup. Below is my code and a screenshot of the webspage and it's elements. I am trying to get the `title` of each post from reddit.com.

*Code*:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.reddit.com/'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
postTitles = soup.find_all("div", {"class", "thing"})
for title in postTitles:
    tClass = title.find("div", {"class", "entry"})
    postTitle = tClass.find("a", {"class", "title"})
    print postTitle
    print "\n\n"
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapingtest.py", line 21, in <module>
    postTitle = tClass.find("a", {"class", "title"})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't an answer, but just in case you missed it, Reddit exposes their data through an API (which has a great Python wrapper). This would make gathering data from Reddit far simpler than with a scraper. https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in how you are applying the attribute checks. Instead of, for example:

```
{"class", "thing"}
```

it should be a dictionary with an attribute name as a key and attribute value as a value:

```
{"class": "thing"}
```

---

Aside from that, by searching for the elements having `thing` classes, you are getting extra elements not having `a` elements with `class="title"`. To fix that, *narrow down your search* by additionally checking for the `data-type` attribute:

```
postTitles = soup.find_all("div", {"class", "thing", "data-type": "link"})
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Reason of The Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapingtest.py", line 21, in <module>
    postTitle = tClass.find("a", {"class", "title"})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

You are getting this because the value of `tClass` is `None`. So we can not call `find` on it. That's what the error message states.

#### Debugging

Please print out the value of `soup` to check the html response you get. Sometimes Reddit blocks repeated requests and sends a simple message instead of the usual listings.

#### Possible Workaround

Use proper user agents and other stuff to simulate the proper behaviour of a human being, browsing reddit on his browser.

You might also want to try doing this using Selenium.

#### Alternatives

Reddit also provides APIs for collecting data and building bots. I personally have never tried it. So not sure what is allowed and what is not. You might look into their APIs to see if it matches your needs.